# Missing hstore column in TileMill!

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill

I made a PostgreSQL with PosGIS Extension DB with the pgsnapshot_schema and loaded an .osm.pbf-file with OSMOSIS into it.
Now i connected it to TileMill, but if i look up into the table i just see columns with the datatype of integer(id, version, User_id,changset_id). But i would like to use Tilemill with the hstore column to select the data and use it for the labels!

In TileMill i wrote into the **Table or subquery: `ways`**;
**Geometry field: `linestring`**

Does anyone know, how i can fix it easily?

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: Should that window even display hstore? You should be able use it in PostGIS layer query, regardless of what this window shows.

Answer (score 1):

Hstore is extension of postgresql so maybe it is not enabled?

Try:

```
Create extension hstore;
```

Comment: I checked out in my PostGIS DB i can see the column, so hstore is enabled.  And the command says the same thanks!
I readed i have to do a Typecast, something like 
 `CAST(layer AS INTEGER)`